# knitr throws error when seq has as.Date arguments

Tags: r, knitr

This works fine in a Rmd chunk:

```
from.date <- as.Date(as.character(date.min), '%Y-%m-%d')
to.date <- as.Date(as.character(date.max), '%Y-%m-%d')
all_dates <- data.frame(created_date = seq(from = from.date, to = to.date, by = "1 day"))
```

but when I try to knit the document I get this:

`Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> data.frame -> seq -> seq.Date`.

I just updated R to 3.4 and RStudio to 1.1.383 last week. Oddly, it was working earlier today, and worked a couple of times after I got the Rmd doc to print out the seq.

If I add `cat("Date range:", as.character(from.date), '-', as.character(to.date), '\n')` to the chunk and execute the chunk, it gives `Date range: 2016-09-01 - 2017-12-21`, so the 'to' argument is definitely finite.

Comment: Works fine for me on `R 3.4.3`,  [`RStudio 1.2.240`](https://dailies.rstudio.com/), `rmarkdown 1.8`, `knitr 1.18` & [`pandoc 2.1`](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/)

Answer (score 0):

Found it. An earlier code block was resetting the date.min and date.max values by taking the min & max of a datetime vector, which produced NA.